# Angular 7 Forms - Conditionally require FormGroup

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular7, angular-forms

I am building a form where the user can set payment options. There is a dropdown to choose which payment method will be used.
For every payment mehod there is a `FormGroup` with options for the selected method:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        method: new FormControl('paypal', {
            validators: [
                Validators.required,
            ],
        }),
        paypal: new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl(null, {
                validators: [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.pattern(EMAIL_PATTERN)
                ],
            }),
        }),
        other: new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl(null, {
                validators: [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.pattern(EMAIL_PATTERN)
                ],
            }),
        }),
    });
```

The issue here is, that the form will only be valid if both `FormGroups` are valid.

But the form should be valid as soon as the `FormGroup` for the selected payment method is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest writing a custom root-level `FromGroup` validator. You essentially have a bespoke validation requirement, and it needs a bespoke validator.

Validators can work on entire `FormGroups` as well as individual `FormControls`, because they are both [AbstractControls](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) under the hood.

[This should point you in the right direction](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)

Edit: for anyone looking for a quick answer here's a stackblitz: [nested form validation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-form-tests)

Comment: So do you think it's easier to just create two different forms?

Comment: Nah I think what you've got is completely fine - it's a good use-case for nested `FormGroup`s - it just needs a simple Validator added at the root `FormGroup` level, to check if any of the nested `FormGroup`s are valid - and then set the validity of the entire root form - for example.

Comment: Alright I'll try and check your answer if it worked :)

Comment: If you can't get it working let me know - I'll throw something together on StackBlitz for you

Comment: It would be really great if you could make a Stackblitz!

Comment: @Florian - I have been on holiday for the last week and forgot about this - do you still need that Stackblitz?

Comment: I would appreciate it :)

Comment: I've just spent a few mins putting together this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-form-tests - I haven't written the custom validator function yet but I'll add another comment on here when I do!

Comment: @Florian check out the stackblitz now, it should have what you need!

Answer (score 2):

Why not disable the controls that aren't needed - then they don't get validated?

Comment: Although creating a custom control is the cleanest way, this worked nicely for my case (field hidden after form group was created)